# How to remove spacing between links in a div?

Tags: html, css

so I'm trying to create some links to different platforms but the spacing between the icons is in my opinion to big and I can't figure out how to decrease it. These are all "a"-tags inside the same div which contains the following styling:

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.link-div{
max-width: 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

These are icons from the font awesome site and the div also contains a font-size via inline-styling, if that matters. Changing that font-size will increase/decrease the size of the icons themselves but will keep the same relative distance between them. The icon classes do not have any separate styling except a couple of transitions/transforms.

If it matters this is what the structure looks like:

```
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d32f88a9a9.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="link-div" style="font-size: 32px;">
    <a href="link-to-where-we're-going"><i class="fab fa-twitch fa-fw"></i></a>
    <a href="link-to-where-we're-going" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-fw"></i></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

and all the styling for the icons looks like this:

```
.fa-twitch{
transition-duration: 200ms;
transform: scale(1, 1);
-moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(1, 1);
color: #bc04fb;
}

.fa-twitch:hover{
transition-duration: 200ms;
transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-moz-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-o-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
}
.fa-facebook-square{
transition-duration: 200ms;
transform: scale(1, 1);
-moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(1, 1);
color: #bc04fb;
}

.fa-facebook-square:hover{
transition-duration: 200ms;
transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-moz-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-o-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
}
```

[image: reference image]

Comment: Have you tried this padding:0px ?

Comment: We need the styling of the a tag, not of the wrapping div. Or do you want to change the placement of the wrapping div?

Comment: @Optimus Yes, it changes nothing

Comment: @cloned So are you saying that it's the a tags that I should change? And if so, do you have any clue how they should be changed? Because they do not currently contain any styling

Comment: then try margin:0

Comment: You could also just put the icons in a list (<ul>) and then style <li> - tags margin. That should make it pretty easy to position them like you want

Comment: @Optimus Changing the margin doesn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: Please add your complete HTML and CSS of that image above! Thanks

Comment: As @AlwaysHelping suggested, we need to see a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see the problem in reality rather than just in an image, so that we can work out what the problem is and be able to help.

Comment: we are not able to see the nested effects of css from your information, please try to inspect a tag and its parents to figure out where you need to apply padding/margin or provide a more workable code sample and try to convert it into a working snippet

Comment: @FluffyKitten Now all the code should be available for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `line-height` - if the line-height is larger than the icon then it is allocating more space to the icon which is resulting in the extra space. If you set the line-height to `1em` for the `a` elements, it removes the space:

```
a { line-height: 1em; }
```

See it working below (I've also made them block elements to appear vertically like in your image, and added a border to the icons so you can see there's no space):

```css
a { 
    line-height: 1em; 
    display: block;
}
.fa-twitch{
transition-duration: 200ms;
transform: scale(1, 1);
-moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(1, 1);
color: #bc04fb;
border:1px solid #aaa;
}
.fa-twitch:hover{
transition-duration: 200ms;
transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-moz-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-o-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
}
.fa-facebook-square{
transition-duration: 200ms;
transform: scale(1, 1);
-moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(1, 1);
color: #bc04fb;
border:1px solid #aaa;
}

.fa-facebook-square:hover{
transition-duration: 200ms;
transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-moz-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-o-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d32f88a9a9.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
  <div class="link-div" style="font-size: 32px;">
    <a href="link-to-where-we're-going"><i class="fab fa-twitch fa-fw"></i></a>
    <a href="link-to-where-we're-going" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-fw"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant and works like a charm! Is it possible to use decimal values for the "em" or is that considered odd?

Comment: @kakkeuno Yes, you can set it to anything, including `px` values to match your icon height. See [the line-height documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height). Just one thing to note about decimal values or percentages is that they get calculated by the browser and if the calcuation doesn't result in whole pixel values, there can be slight variations or gapping.

Answer (score 1):

Edited it with real icons so you can see how it looks as an example.
I usually use a List for Icon-Columns.

```css
.link-div ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.link-div ul li {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.link-div ul li a{
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div class="link-div">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.link-div a {
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
}
```

It should remove all padding and margins from your links.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything

Comment: @kakkeuno try changing `.link-div a` to `.link-div a i`

Comment: Edit: it seems like padding is for sure the way to go, margin moves it to left and right but the padding seems to be as low as it possibly can go

Comment: @kakkeuno try inspecting the icons and see which element causes the spacing